# Returning a blank page in hello world java servlet when submit button is clicked

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlets

I have tried everything to get this servlet working, and after downloading                     several older JRE's and several older versions of Apache tomcat, it still      didn't work.  Right now I am using Kepler for Java EE with JRE v1.7 and           Tomcat v7.  Below is my java source and html--I suspect that the problem is     with the doGet method itself, because I think I have the file paths named      correctly, but I am still returning a blank page.  Albeit the problem          could be with the form action--I am entirely new to eclipse.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
   <html>
       <head> <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
          <title>Insert title here</title> 
       </head> 
     <body> 
        <form  action="/HelloWorld/HelloServlet" method="get">
            <input type="submit"  value="go to hello servlet"/>
        </form> 
     </body> 
   </html>`
```

HelloServaled.java

```
package com.tutorials.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HelloServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
  /* @see Servlet#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest request,                                                                                                           >        HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  >      response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request,                           >        HttpServletResponse response)
     */

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse           >             response) throws ServletException, IOException {


             PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
             out.println("I am in go get mehtod" );

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request,                                            >       HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse               >       response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPut(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
     */
    protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse                    >       response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: Replace this 
<form  action="/HelloWorld/HelloServlet" method="get">
            <input type="submit"  value="go to hello servlet"/>
 </form>  with

<form  action="/HelloServlet" method="get">
            <input type="submit"  value="go to hello servlet"/>
 </form>

i.e remove HelloWorld from form action tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue lies in a mismatch between your form's `action` attribute being different than your servlet's mapping.

Your annotation: (`@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")`) is telling the application server to listen for requests to "/HelloServlet", eg: `http://eample.com/HelloServlet` which it is.

Your form, on the other hand, has it's action set to `/HelloWorld/HelloServlet`, meaning that the post request goes to `http://example.com/HelloWorld/HelloServlet`

So when your browser posts there, the application handles it how it should, it doesn't, because your servlet isn't listening to anything there.